Ambigious access on function inherited from 2 class
Information
I have a class RenderWindow that inherit from RenderTarget2D and RenderTarget3D:
class API RenderWindow : public RenderTarget2D, public RenderTarget3D

Both RenderTarget2D and RenderTarget3D have a function draw, they both have specialization of the function. For example:
class RenderTarget2D
{
    public:
        void draw(Drawable2D);
        void draw(Vertex2D);
}

class RenderTarget3D
{
    public:
        void draw(Drawable3D);
        void draw(Vertex3D);
}


Their are no identical function definition from RenderTarget2D and RenderTarget3D.

DrawableXD is an interface and VertexXD is a concret class.
Problem:
When using RenderWindow::draw with a class inheriting from Drawable2D (for example, doesn't work with any specialization type), I have the following error:
error: request for member 'draw' is ambiguous

And provide me with all the possible specialization of the function, like:
note: candidates are: void RenderTarget3D::draw(Vertex3D)
note:                 void RenderTarget3D::draw(Drawable3D)
note:                 void RenderTarget2D::draw(Vertex2D)
note:                 void RenderTarget2D::draw(Drawable2D)
...

I wan't my compiler to select the correct type specialization for the function, but as I understood, because RenderWindow is derived from both RenderTarget2D and RenderTarget3D the compiler isn't able to choose the correct function.
Question:
How can I keep this 2 separted class and make the function specialization work? Or if the issue really come only from the fact that I use 2 inherited class to perform the specialization, what kind of change am I looking for?
# EDIT
Minimal reproduciable example:
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class RenderTarget2D
{
    public:
        void draw(int a)
        {
            std::cout << "2D | int" << std::endl;
        }

        void draw(std::vector<int> çarg)
        {
            std::cout << "2D | vector" << std::endl;
        }
};

class RenderTarget3D
{
    public:
        void draw(float a)
        {
            std::cout << "3D | float" << std::endl;
        }

        void draw(std::array<float, 3> çarg)
        {
            std::cout << "3D | array" << std::endl;
        }
};

class RenderWindow : public RenderTarget2D, public RenderTarget3D
{
};

int main()
{
    RenderWindow win{};

    win.draw(1);
    return 0;
}


We need a [mcve]. Something that we can copy/paste into a compiler and reproduce the said issue/problem.

Overloading occurs between functions defined in the same scope. The 2D and 3D versions of those two functions are not defined in the same scope, so there is no overloading in a class derived from both of those classes.

Sinde note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Terminology: these functions are not "specializatons". They are functions; full stop. Templates can be specialized; ordinary functions cannot.

Minor point: the minimal reproducible example could be smaller, with only one version of draw in each of the base classes.

Dupe: Overloading member function among multiple base classes and How can I resolve a function call ambiguity when multiple base classes have a member function with the same name?. I would also recommend searching and then researching before asking any question as the downvote button recommends.

How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

You can't "mix-in" overloads like that.
You can solve it by bringing all functions into RenderWindow's scope:
class API RenderWindow : public RenderTarget2D, public RenderTarget3D
{
public:
    using RenderTarget2D::draw;
    using RenderTarget3D::draw;    
   /// ...
};

Or, you know, use different names.
